# Lines get split on preg_replace usage

Tags: php, preg-replace

My code-

```
$input = "this text is for highlighting a text if it exists in a string. Let us check if it works or not";

$pattern ="/if/";
$replacement= "H1Fontbracket"."if"."H1BracketClose";

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $input);
```

Now the problem is that when i run this code, it splits into multiple lines, what else do i need to do so that i am able to get it in one line

Comment: There's probably a better way to do it, but couldn't you just concatenate the return value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str_replace` rather than `preg_replace`. `preg_replace` will return an array of strings, and `str_replace` will just return the string:

```
echo str_replace($pattern, $replacement, $input);
```

Comment: Getting - Warning: join() [function.join]: Argument must be an array, on using -echo join(preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $input));

Comment: even this is not working :-echo str_replace($pattern, $replacement, $input); Changed pattern to $pattern ="if"; ..let me know what iam missing

Comment: $replacement="<h1 style='display:inline;'>".$pattern."</h1>"; This is what i need to add to break line spacing problem from **H1 Tag**. Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Sorry currently not having much points to vote up/down :( will surely do it in the future :) Clicked on Accepted answer :)

Comment: `preg_replace` only returns an array if the subject is an array. Correct usage could be `preg_replace('/\\bif\\b/', '<h1>$0</h1>', $input)`. The `\\b` means to match at word boundaries, so words containing the letters `if` won't be affected.

Comment: PHP manual: "If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions), you should always use this function instead of preg_replace()."

Comment: @arasmussen If you use str_replace here, you'll catch cases of `if` inside words too. If that's ok, then using str_replace is great. But if not, preg_replace with some word boundaries in the pattern will be more correct.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by multiple lines? Of course it'll show up as multiple lines on a webpage if you wrap the `if`s in header tags. Headers are block elements. And more importantly, headers are *headers*. Not for highlighting text.

If you want to highlight something with HTML, you should probably use a `span` with a class, or you could use the HTML5 element [`mark`](http://html5doctor.com/draw-attention-with-mark/):

```
$input = "this text is for highlighting a text if it exists in an iffy string.";
echo preg_replace('/\\bif\\b/', '<span class="highlighted">$0</span>', $input);
echo preg_replace('/\\bif\\b/', '<mark>$0</mark>', $input);
```

The `\\b` is to only match `if` words, and not just the `if` letters, which might be part of a different word. Then in your CSS you can decide how the marked words should show up:

```
.highlighted { background: yellow }
mark { background: yellow }
```

Or whatever. I would recommend that you read up a bit on how HTML and CSS works if you're going to make web pages :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, now i got the point why that adding "inline" clicked once i used that stuff in <h1 style='display:inline;'>" . thx a lot :)

Comment: Um, why am I downvoted? Isn't this what you were looking for?

Comment: I dont know how :( when i m clicking on Vote up it is saying --"Vote Up requires 15 reputation" , i have not down voted any of the comment but i really dont know how it is showing MINUS for the comments :(

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$input = "this text is for highlighting a text if
it exists in a string. Let us check if it works or not";

$pattern="if";
$replacement="<h1>". $pattern. "</h1>";
$input= str_replace($pattern,$replacement,$input);

echo "$input";
```

Comment: I am getting split lines only when iam using h1 tag, i changed tags to bold added <font style="background-color:#EEE882;"> and these all working fine. Any guess why it was so? my php version -5.2.6

Comment: $replacement="<h1 style='display:inline;'>".$pattern."</h1>"; This is what i need to add to break line spacing problem from **H1 Tag**. Thanks all for your suggestions

Comment: You can add css inside head tag `<head> <style type="text/css">  h1 {display:inline; } </style> </head>`

Comment: Using the H1 Tag for this is just plain wrong. H1 is for headers, not for highlighting text. It's the wrong tag for the job. You should most likely use span or mark instead.

Comment: @Svish, you cannot blame me for his choice of tags

Answer (score -2):

```
function highlight($str,$search){
    $patterns = array('/\//', '/\^/', '/\./', '/\$/', '/\|/',
        '/\(/', '/\)/', '/\[/', '/\]/', '/\*/', '/\+/', 
        '/\?/', '/\{/', '/\}/', '/\,/');
    $replace = array('\/', '\^', '\.', '\$', '\|', '\(', '\)', 
        '\[', '\]', '\*', '\+', '\?', '\{', '\}', '\,');

    $search = preg_replace($patterns, $replace, $search);
    $search = str_replace(" ","|",$search);
    return @preg_replace("/(^|\s)($search)/i",'${1}<span class=highlight>${2}</span>',$str);
}
```